# How to center text vertically in table cell in LaTex tabular environment?

Tags: latex, tabular

I would like to center the text in each cell horizontally and vertically. With the code below, the text is centered horizontally but not vertically and appears at the top of the cells. Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{tabular}{| L{1cm} | C{5cm} | C{5cm} | C{5cm} |} \hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.4}& \color{white}Cell 1 & \color{white}Cell 2 & \color{white}Cell 3 \\[30pt] \hline
\cellcolor[gray]{.4}\color{white}Cell 4 & Cell 5 & Cell 6 & Cell 7 \\[100pt] \hline


\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, please, please, have a look at how to create nice looking tables, e.g. the [user manual of the `booktabs` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf). Putting your data into a data prison is bad. Making a zebra strip table is worse. Doing both at the same time is just horrible.

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}

\author{author names}
\shorttitle{subtitle}
\title{title}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}


\noindent%
\begin{tblr}{
  hlines,
  vlines,
  row{1} = {bg=gray,fg=white},
  rows = {ht=2cm},
  columns = {halign=c},
  colspec = {Q[1cm,bg=gray,fg=white] XXX},
  } 
  & Cell 1 & Cell 2 & Cell 3 \\
  Cell 4 & Cell 5 & Cell 6 & Cell 7 \\
\end{tblr}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help and feedback. I am very new to LaTex. What do you mean by putting data into a "data prison" ?

Comment: @Marie Data prison describes cells that have rules on all four sites. It is better to not use any vertical lines in tables at all.

Comment: please explain what you exactly added to the code and why.

Comment: @asa I don't know if you figured it out yet, but alas, what was changed was the 3 columntypes from "\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}>>>p<<<{#1}}" to "\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}>>>m<<<{#1}}"